# Does $x \cdot \sin \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) = 1$ has solutions?

Tags: transcendental-equations, numerical-calculus

A look to the plot show to you that the function $f(x) = x \cdot \sin \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) - 1 $ has no zero near the origin. Wolframalpha software says that $ x \cdot \sin \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) = 1$ if $x \approx 5.16\cdot 10^{15}$ but I suspect this huge number is a wrong solution due to numerical problems. Is it true that for some $x$, far away from the origin, the equation $$  x \cdot \sin \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) = 1 $$ is satisfied? Can, far away, $f(x)= x \cdot \sin \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)$ exceeds 1?

Comment: No it cannot because the only solution to $\sin{(y)}=y$ is when $y=0$ but clearly $y=1/x\ne 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that:
$$x \cdot \sin \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) = \frac{ \sin \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)}{\left( \frac{1}{x} \right)}.$$

Moreover, observe that:

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{ \sin \left( \frac{1}{x} \right)}{\left( \frac{1}{x} \right)} = 1.$$

This means that your function "is equal to $1$" for $x \to +\infty$. Numerically, $x \to +\infty$ stands for a huge number. The solution provided by Wolfram ($x \approx 5.16\cdot 10^{15}$) is indeed a huge number.

Comment: Thank you but "the function has limit 1" and "the function never touches 1" are two different statements.  It does not seem to me that this answers the question.

Comment: @FaustoVezzaro yes, this partially answer to your question. The most important thing is that $\sin(y) \leq |y|$ for all $y \in \mathbb{R}$, and the equal sign holds iff $y = 0.$ In your case, substitute $y$ with $\frac{1}{x}$. Observe that $\frac{1}{x} = 0$ is never satisfied for any real number $x$. However, it "reaches" 0 at infinity, and this is why a good numerical solver will provide you answers like $x = 5.16 \cdot 10^{15}$.

Comment: $\sin(y)\leq |y|$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$ solve your problem. Consider $\frac{1}{x} = y > 0$. Then:
$$\sin(y)\leq y\Rightarrow\frac{\sin(y)}{y} \leq 1\Rightarrow x\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) \leq 1.$$
The equal is never satisfied, since there is no $x>0$ such that $y=\frac{1}{x}=0.$
Similar argumens hold for $\frac{1}{x} = y < 0$.
Again, $y = \frac{1}{x} = 0$ is satisfied only for $x \to +\infty$. This doesn't mean that $0$ is ever reached. Numerical solver doesn't know that. They just try to give a reasonable solution. The user should be able to interpret the results of calculator.

Comment: Wolframalpha is not a trivial numerical solver. It is powerful and often able to solve strange things, like a human brain (so to speack!). For this reason it seemed strange to me an answer like a huge number in place of "no solution". Probably the developers would consider this a bug.

Comment: @FaustoVezzaro I don't think it is a bug. A good **numerical** solver like wolfram should answer in that way! Instead, a **symbolic** solver should provide a smarter answer.

Comment: Why do you say that Wolframalpha is just a numerical solver? It is a powerful symbolic solver that usually works well. That is why I'm a little surprised by this behavior.

Comment: @FaustoVezzaro well, maybe you are right. Anyway, your question is not about the behavior of Wolfram. This can be the object of another question. So, please, if you find a satisfactory answer to your original question, accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider substituting \frac{1}{x}:

$$
x \cdot \sin \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) = 1\\
\iff\\
\sin \left( \frac{1}{x} \right) = \frac{1}{x}\\
\iff\\
\sin (z) = z\\
$$

This is only satisfied if $z=0$, implying $x=\infty$, which is what wolfram was trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

$$x \sin (1/x) =1 \implies \sin (\frac{1}{x})=\frac{1}{x} \implies \sin y =y.$$
But $$y > \sin y,~ if ~ y>0 ;~ y < \sin y ~ ~ if ~ ~ y<0.$$~
The only solution the last equation may have is $y=0$, but it is not allowed here as it would mean $x=\infty$. So the given equation cannot have a real root.